# `join': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

Tags: ruby, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have the Ruby script below that is using the Anemone Gem and outputting the results to a CSV file using the built in Ruby CSV.  I am receiving this error when the script runs:

```
`join': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
```

Ruby Script:

```
Anemone.crawl("http://www.<website>.com") do |anemone|
anemone.on_every_page do |page|
title = page.doc.xpath("//head/title").text rescue nil

CSV.open(CSV_FILE_PATH, "a") do |csv|

  csv << [title, page.url, page.body]
  end
 end
end
```

I have tried a variety of recommendations to force encoding or ignore the issues but none of them seem to work.  I have isolated the issue to the CSV writing and specifically on the 'title' attribute of the Anemone object.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you print the encodings of the three items in the array you add to the CSV?

Comment: @Linuxios, how can I do that?

Comment: Well... it's a bit old I know, but did you found any answer to solve this ? I got the same issue...